# Can you add several Schedule triggers into one Frends process?

Tags: triggers, schedule, frends

I want my Frends process to have Schedule triggers with several schedules. For example, each Wednesday at 07:00 and each Monday on 12:30. Can I add both?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, just add multiple different Schedule triggers. It is strange that [documentation](https://docs.frends.com/en/articles/2206739-schedule-trigger) doesn't mention that.

Full disclosure: I work in a team that made FRENDS.